# Windows Server 08 R2 file share File locking, OSX clients

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, server-message-block, locking

I've spent the last two weeks banging my head against this wall. I think I'm starting to understand the problem though. I manage a design company and they have 5 macs (OSX 10.5/.6/.7) connected over SMB to a Windows 2008 R2 file server, another machine functions as Domain Controller (that might not matter).

All the macs can connect ok, no issues finding the server or logging in. For the most part things are ok. The problem is files locking up. I thought it was a permissions issue at first but it seems to be file locking. The users open a file; .ind, .pdf etc the file opens, the software reads it and closes it. That's fine, but the folder above the folder locks, it can't be moved and it can't be renamed.

Eg:

- /Working/Project01/Imagefiles/image.pdf
- /Finished/

The user opens image.pdf, closes it and wants to move the whole Project01 folder into Finished. It gives a username/pass dialogue and then does nothing, no error, or just does nothing. Trying to rename gives a dialogue that says you don't have permission. It looks like it's looking for permission locally, which is why I spent about a week looking at that.

Eventually I found that Finder on the macs seems to be keeping the folders open. I can work around it by Killing finder, remounting the shared drive or closing the file through the server manager but this just proves the theory it's not a solution.

Has anyone dealt with this problem?

Comment: please pay more attention to your formatting. as originally written, your post was a single wall of text and completely unreadable. i've edited it to improve the readability.

Comment: We've just started getting this exact problem too. Looking into it now so I'll post back if I find a solution. At the moment the work around is copy the pdf onto the Desktop then open it from there, then we can move the folder.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue or two separate issues but I found on Mountain Lion that MDWorker seems to be locking .DS_Store files within new or worked on directories. The users tend to copy in a template tree of directories when they start a new project, you can see MDWorker working away in the folders as soon as you drop them in and while it's working on one you can't move it or the ones above it.

Comment: For those finding this. I spent three months searching, configing, updating and never found a fix. Eventually we gave up on Windows Server's native support and bought ExtreamZ IP, it wasn't cheap.

Answer (score -1):

Use Icon view instead of list view until Apple fix the bug.

Comment: What bug is this? This answer is exceedingly low on detail.